# Execute multiple cURL requests

Tags: php, curl

I have created a script which pulls the HTTP Response/Code from the header of a single website/URL. This works fine.

```
<!-- Form for URL input -->
<div style="margin: 20% auto; max-width:250px; font-size:18px; font-family: monospace;">

<form name="open_linktest" action="" method='GET'>
    <input type="text" name="linktest" value="" style="font-size: 18px; width: 250px;">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" style="font-size: 22px; padding: 4px;">Check IP / URL</button>
</form>
<!-- GET SELECT VALUES USING PHP -->

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['linktest'])){
        $linktest = $_GET['linktest'];
        // Using $linktest variable
    }



$url = "$linktest"; // $url GET data from 'linktest' form input
$ch = curl_init($url); // initiate curl on $url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); // Set curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,true);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<400){
  echo "$linktest" . '<br />Status = Running Okay <br />';
  echo "HTTP Code Response: $httpcode";

} else {
  echo "$linktest" . '<br />Status = Not working <br />';
  echo "HTTP Code Response: $httpcode";

}
?>
</div>
```

I am looking to input multiple URLs - and have it shoot out the response code & status of each one. (Also IP - ping will be added later).

```
<?php
$urls = array(
"http://google.com"
"http://php.net"
"https://pfsense.dataquestdigital.com.au"
);

// Class to run parallel GET requests and return the transfer
class ParallelGet
{
  function __construct($urls)
  {
    // Create get requests for each URL
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach($urls as $i => $url)
    {
      $ch[$i] = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($bhash4win_Curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // extra lines from original single curl code to call http header info
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    //
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
    }

    // Start performing the request - $mh is multi $ch
    do {
        $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
    } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    // Loop and continue processing the request
    while ($runningHandles && $execReturnValue == CURLM_OK) {
      // Wait forever for network
      $numberReady = curl_multi_select($mh);
      if ($numberReady != -1) {
        // Pull in any new data, or at least handle timeouts
        do {
          $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
        } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
      }
    }

    // Check for any errors
    if ($execReturnValue != CURLM_OK) {
      trigger_error("Curl multi read error $execReturnValue\n", E_USER_WARNING);
    }

    // Extract the content - $urls giving $i loop counter variables = put into $url for each loop
    foreach($urls as $i => $url)
    {
      // Check for errors
      $curlError = curl_error($ch[$i]);
      if($curlError == "") {
        $res[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]);
        $res[$i] = curl_multi_getinfo();
        echo $res[$i]."<br />\n";
    echo "hello";

      } else {
        print $i."error to get a result"."\n";
        echo "borked";
      }

      // Remove and close the handle
      curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
      curl_close($ch[$i]); 
    }
    // Clean up the curl_multi handle


    curl_multi_close($mh);
    }
}
?>
```

Is there a more simple way to do this? Am I going in the right direction - have an array of the URL's, run foreach / curl_multi_init..

Is it possible to do curl_multi_getinfo() to pull the headers?

Comment: You should post the code into your question

Comment: Fixed now. I just thought it would be easier linking.